# Error and not receiving email from contact form

Tags: php, html, ajax

i am trying to create a contact form that just send the form to my email, i am having a couple of problems with it, when the user submits the form it responds with an error but also the message saying it is sent correctly, however i am not receiving any of the messages.

Here is the error

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: contactName1 in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/site/contact.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
```

If it helps i am running my website on a local server (lampp).

Here is the php

```
    <?php


include('scripts/connection.php');


$consubject= test_input($_POST['contactSubject1']);
$conname= test_input($_POST['contactName1']);
$conemail= test_input($_POST['contactEmail1']);
$conmessage= test_input($_POST['contactMessage1']);

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}


$email_to = "myemail@gmail.com";






    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$conemail)) {


    echo "The Email address ".$conemail." is not valid";

  }else{

      // create email headers

        $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



        function clean_string($string) {

          $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

          return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

        }



        $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($conname)."\n";

        $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($conmessage)."\n";


 $from="From: $conname<$conemail>\r\nReturn-path: $conemail";
        $consubject="Message sent using your contact form";
        mail("myemail@gmail.com", $consubject, $email_message, $from); 


       // echo "Thanks for your message";

  }


?>
```

Here is the javascript

```
$("#contactSubmit").click(function(){
        var contactSubject = $("#contactSubject").val();
        var contactName = $("#contactName").val();
        var contactEmail = $("#contactEmail").val();
        var contactMessage = $("#contactMessage").val();

        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
        var dataStringContact = 'contactSubject1='+ contactSubject + 'contactName1='+ contactName + '&contactEmail1='+ contactEmail + '&contactMessage1='+ contactMessage;
        if(contactSubject===''||contactName===''||contactEmail===''||contactMessage==='')
        {
            alert("Please Fill All Fields");
        }
        else
        {
            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contact.php",
            data: dataStringContact,
            cache: false,
            success: function(resultContact){
                alert(resultContact);
                document.forms['contactForm'].reset();
            }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Here is the html

```
<form name="contactForm">

                                    <input id="contactSubject" name="contactSubject" type="text"class="inputs" placeholder="Subject" /> 
                                    <br> 
                                    <input id="contactName" name="contactName" type="text"class="inputs" placeholder="Name" /> 
                                    <br> 
                                    <input id="contactEmail" name="contactEmail" type="text"class="inputs" placeholder="E-mail" /> 
                                    <br> 
                                     <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="contactMessage" name="contactMessage" type="text" class="inputs" placeholder="Write your message..."></textarea>  

                                    <br> <br>
                                     <input id="contactSubmit" type="button" name="contactSubmit" class="submitButton" value="Submit" />

                                 </form>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `&`in `dataStringContact` variable (8th line in JavaScript code snippet):

```
var dataStringContact = 'contactSubject1='+ contactSubject + '&contactName1='+ contactName + '&contactEmail1='+ contactEmail + '&contactMessage1='+ contactMessage; 
                                                              ^
```

Comment: Thankyou that fixed the error, silly mistake by me, however i am still not receiving any emails, even though it tells me the message was sent succesfully, any ideas why?

Comment: @AlHennessey: see the SPAM folder in your mail and/or server log where is error. The PHP script is okay now.

Comment: iv checked the spam and theres no email, is it because i am running it from localhost and not an actual hosting server?

Comment: @AlHennessey: if you haven't set SMTP server in local server, you can't send (and on Gmail receive) any mails. So move the script to server and it will work.

Comment: thankyou for yourhelp, i will wait until i upload it to the permanent hosting server and then test from there, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You have to first check whether you have properly setup the SMTP server. 
If you have not setup anything then I would suggest you to use any third party libraries to send email like `PHPMailer`
[PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebmail)